# How to use masstransit's retry policy with sagas?

Tags: masstransit

Configuring a RetryPolicy inside a ReceiveEndpoint of a queue used for store messages from commands and events (as appears bellow) appears does not works when the queue is a saga endpoint queue.

This configuration works fine (note the endpoint **RegisterOrderServiceQueue**):

```
  ...
  var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
  {
       cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.RegisterOrderServiceQueue, e =>
      {
           e.UseRetry(Retry.Except<ArgumentException>().Immediate(3));
  ...
```

...Bus **RetryPolicy** configuration on windows service to run the Saga state machine does not work (note the endpoint **SagaQueue**):

```
    ...
var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.SagaQueue, e =>
    {
        e.UseRetry(Retry.Except<ArgumentException>().Immediate(3));
...
```

StateMachine class source code that throws an ArgumentException:

```
...
During(Registered,
    When(ApproveOrder)
        .Then(context =>
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Test for monitoring sagas");
            context.Instance.EstimatedTime = context.Data.EstimatedTime;
            context.Instance.Status = context.Data.Status;
        })
        .TransitionTo(Approved),
...
```

But when **ApproveOrder** occurs the RetryPolicy rules are ignored, and connecting a ConsumeObserver in the bus that Sagas is connected, the ConsumeFault's method is executed 5 times (that is the default behavior of masstransit).

This should work? There is any missconception on my configurations?

Comment: I suspect that the exception type is changing to a `SagaException`, with your `ArgumentException` as an `InnerException`. You could use a custom filter policy of `SagaException(x => x.InnerException is ArgumentException)` to catch your specific exception -- I think.

Comment: Is it, Thanks! I will try create a custom policy like you suggest now

Comment: FYI, issue added and fixed: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/558